# Dual row getting inserted in DB through Oracle Form

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I have created a simple Oracle form where I am asking user 4-5 inputs and on click of Button(when-button-pressed trigger) I have written an insert statement, then commit.

When I am pressing the Button 2 records with same details are getting inserted. i am unable to understand why. Oracle message is comming as FRM40400 1 transection applied and saved. But in DB table 2 rows are comming with the same data. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Forms just did what you instructed it to - to insert two rows. How?

- that's - I presume - data block (i.e. based on some table)
- it means that all values you insert into fields are **automatically** inserted into the underlying table as soon as you commit
- the second rows gets inserted with `insert` statement you wrote behind the trigger

  - remove it; you don't need it. You *would* if it were a control block but - apparently - it is not
  - if you want to keep the button (which just commits), OK - leave it, just remove `insert` statement from it

---

It seems that you don't quite understand how Forms work. Read some documentation about it, for your own sake. Online Forms Help system (the one that shows up when you press `F1` key) should get you started.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes it is a datablock. The Table in which datablock is made contains 10 columns, in frontend user is displayed only five and in remaining fields I have putting values/nulls based on different condition. So I want to use the insert query instead of automatically going into the table of datablock. Can you please help me in doing this.

Comment: Yes I am new to Forms, and running behind the deadline to submit one project assignment. Also F1 -help is not supported in my software verison (don't know why). It would be helpful if you can provide some links to start from basic. Thanks

Comment: Didn't you get any documentation already? How are you supposed to work with a tool you don't know? Ask your ... boss, teacher, whoever gave you that assignment  - that you are unable to do that because you lack in basic knowledge. Nobody can expect you to do that out of nowhere.